# Link between norm of weights/coefficients and smoothness

Tags: machine-learning, regularization

We often avoid overfitting by penalizing the norm of the weights/coefficients (in a classic Ridge or Lasso regression). I understand that we want smooth functions as they will be more likely to generalize. But what is the link between smoothness and norm?

Comment: I wanted to write weight's norm obviously.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "link", are you looking for a theoretical explanation of penalized regression or something more practical?

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I am looking for a theoretical explanation. Why penalizing high coefficients leads to smoother functions ?

Comment: As I see it, the penalisation force the coefficients to shrink, in the case of Lasso actually some coefficients become zero. The smoothness is a consequence of shrinking the coefficients toward zero.

Comment: For instance LASSO can be used as a variable selection model, and it's obvious that by reducing the complexity of your model i.e. by reducing the number of covariates the over-fitting will be reduced and hence the approximation will be smoother. (The smoothest function you could imagine is a straight horizontal  line where you include only an intercept).

Comment: "The smoothness is a consequence of shrinking the coefficients toward zero." This is the part that is unclear to me. For instance, you can have a weights vector with only one non zero element. You can put it as high as you want, the function is still going to be pretty smooth.

Comment: Is going to be "pretty" smooth, yes; but by shrinking the coefficient you will somehow increase the smoothness. For instance in a function of the form $ax^2+bx+c$ if you shrink $a$ toward zero you end up with a linear function that is more smooth than the quadratic polynomial (smooth here is not used in a proper mathematical sense), in the same way if you shrink $b$ to zero you end up with an estimation of the form $c=\bar{X}$ which in turn is even smoother. If you shrink also $c$ , I don't know , it seems pretty meaningless. Although, I understand your point, and it's pretty interesting.

Comment: Given that the regression methods you mention fit functions that are linear w.r.t. the inputs, could you say more precisely what you mean by smoothness? I.e. in what sense is one linear function more smooth than another?